# peewee error on newly created save()

Tags: python, peewee

Making myself familiar with peewee, I stumbled upon the following weird behavior: Given a class similar to this

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    str = CharField(primary_key=True)
```

executing

```
instance = Test(str = 'something')
instance.save()
```

gives an obscure error complaining about some 'WHERE':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3830, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 5165, in save
    rows = self.update(**field_dict).where(self._pk_expr()).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3458, in execute
    return self.database.rows_affected(self._execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2939, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3837, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3656, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 135, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3830, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

However, directly creating the instance using

```
instance = Test.create(str = 'something')
```

works as expected. This only seems to happen when the attribute used is a primary key.
A similar issue seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038185/python-peewee-save-doesnt-work-as-expected) question where no error is produced, but no database entry either. I'm aware of the workaround from the solution but just curious about this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `save(force_insert=True)` when using a non-auto-incrementing primary key.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#non-integer-primary-keys-composite-keys-and-other-tricks

Comment: Thanks, indeed I wasn't aware this was an intended behavior. However, the error cause is really confusing. An error message leading more into the right direction would be great!